# Is there any algorithm to judge a string is meaningful

Tags: algorithm, string

The problem is， I have to scan executable file and find out the strings for analysis, use [strings.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439) from sysinternals. However, How to distinguish meaningful strings and the trivial strings, Is there any algorithm or thought to solve this problem(statistics? probability?).

for example:
extract strings from strings.exe(part of all strings)

```
S`A
waA
RmA
>rA
5xA
GetModuleHandleA
LocalFree
LoadLibraryA
LocalAlloc
GetCommandLineW
```

From empirical judgement, the last five strings is meaningful, and the first 5 ones are not.
So how to solve this problem, do not use a dictionary like black list or white list.

Comment: or use some dictionary with bad n-gramms of letters

Comment: At least for this example, `strings -n4` would also serve to discriminate. More complicated, you could populate a digram or trigram table and select words that more closely match English digram or trigram tables.

Answer (score 5):

Simple algorithm: Break candidate strings into words on first caps/whitespace/digits, and then compare words against some dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

use N-Grams
N-Gram will tell you what is the probability that word is meaningfull. Read about markov chains and n-grams (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) . Treat each letter as state, and take the set of meaningfull and meaningless words. For example:

Meaningless word are `B^^@, #AT`

Normal words: `BOOK, CAT`

create two Language models for them (trigram will be the best) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model

and now you can check in which model word was probably generated and take language model with probability greater than in other one. this will satisfy your condition

remember that you need set of meaningless words ( i think around 1000 will be ok) and not meaningless

Answer (score 0):

Is there a definite rule for meaningful words? Or are they simply words from dictionary?
If they are words from dictionary, then you can use [trie's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296618/what-is-the-most-common-use-of-the-trie-data-structure)

you can look up a word until the next char is not capitalized. if its capitalized then start from beginning of the trie and look for the next word.

Just my 2 cents.

- Ivar